# Java Gradle Build: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, heroku, gradle, build, dependencies

My `build.gradle` file is as following

```
apply plugin: 'java' sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral() }


dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'io.javalin:javalin:1.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.4'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25' }

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect {"$it.name"}.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'products.ProductAPI'
        )
    } }

task stage {
    dependsOn 'build'
    dependsOn 'clean'
    build.mustRunAfter clean }
```

Trying to build a java application with gradle and deploy it to a heroku server. I have some issues on `java -jar build/libs/MyApp-0.0.1.jar` as it returns the following:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   io/javalin/Javalin    at products.ProductAPI.main(ProductAPI.java:7)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.javalin.Javalin   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: Try compile group 'io.javalin:javalin:1.3.0'

Comment: tried it, and it didn't work unfortunetely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run your app without any `NoClassDefFoundError`, you should have your dependencies in the runtime class path. Creating a fat jar is the simplest solution. Change your jar section like below;

```
jar {
    manifest {
       attributes(
          'Class-Path': configurations.compile.files.collect {"$it.name"}.join(' '),
          'Main-Class': 'products.ProductAPI')}
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

run `gradle build` command and jar with dependencies will be created.
Other way is to add jars to runtime class path are; with `java -cp` flag. (Also If your application has already a classpath folder configured, copying dependencies in this folder will add them to the classpath)

Comment: If the dependencies are configured with implementation scope, fat jar can be created with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49284432/5210117