# How do I create an executable fat JAR with Gradle with implementation dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, executable-jar, gradle-plugin, fatjar

I've got a simple project in Gradle 4.6 and would like to make an executable JAR of it. I've tried `shadow`, `gradle-fatjar-plugin`, `gradle-one-jar`, `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` plugins but neither of them adds my dependencies declared as `implementation` (I don't have any `compile` ones). It works with `compile` e.g. for `gradle-one-jar` plugin but I would like to have `implementation` dependencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating runnable JAR with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721119/creating-runnable-jar-with-gradle)

Comment: You tried spring boot? That's the only reasonable option. Without that - expect problems as your project develops. One of the gotchas is repackaging which results in skipping some files.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.package.YourClass'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
 }
```

Be sure to replace `com.package.YourClass` with the fully qualified class name containing `static void main( String args[] )`.

This will pack the runtime dependencies.  Check the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) if you need more info.

Comment: whats the name of the fat jar and in which dir do I find it?

Comment: @VijayKumar Mine is under `build/libs`.

Comment: You may want to use `configurations.compileClasspath.filter{ it.exists() }.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }`. That way if you have non-existant classpath entries it won't get hung up. I'm using Kotlin so the java source classpath entry didn't have anything and it got pretty cranky.

Comment: When I use this code, all of the library classes are included in the uberjar, but the classes in the source directory aren't.

Comment: @user64141 Your source files has to be in the directory src/main/java next to build.gradle file, that you added this code. (which is the standard convention) If they are in another folder they wont be included in the jar. I suggest using standard folder structure. This is the only case that I can think that cause your described problem

Comment: Why isn't this included when a Gradle project is created in the IDE?

Comment: What exactly does this line do? The from { configurations ...}

Comment: does not work anymore in newer gradle version. try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61198352/393657

Comment: Note to self: this worked for me with JDK 11, Gradle 6.4

Comment: Thanks! I was using `into('lib') { from configurations.runtime }` in gradle 2.8 so just had to update it to `into('lib') { from configurations.runtimeClasspath }` in gradle 6.7.1.

Comment: This post works in Gradle 6.8.2. Thank you

Comment: Man, you saved me a lot of time. There was a howto on the net but it was buggy :)

Comment: See [Gradle "Entry .classpath is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68922734/432903) for duplicate strategy

Comment: Note it's `attributes(` with a ROUND bracket, not curly brace :D

Answer (score 32):

Based on the accepted answer, I needed to add one more line of code:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.yourpackage.Main'
  }
  archiveClassifier = "all"
  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
  with jar
}
```

Without this additional line, it omitted my source files and only added the dependencies:

```
configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
```

For newer gradle (7+), you may see this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':fatJar'.
> Entry [some entry here] is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please 
refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy
 for details.
```

If this happens add a `duplicatesStrategy` such as `duplicatesStrategy "exclude"` to the `fatJar` task.

And likewise, for Gradle 7+, you have to just remove the `configuration.compile.collect` line because it is no longer a valid configuration in this version of gradle.

Comment: This worked where all the others didn't for Gradle 6.0.1. Mysteriously, the second line didn't seem to be required in Gradle 4.x, but my old build config suddenly stopped creating fat JARs once upgraded to Gradle 6 or 5.

Comment: Gradle 6.5 reports the following warning: 
The compile configuration has been deprecated for resolution. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please resolve the compileClasspath configuration instead. Replacing "compile" by "compileClasspath" fixed it.

Comment: Worked perfectly, not sure how you found this but you are doing gods work!!

Comment: @jbel Thanks! I stumbled upon it by combining info from another post

Comment: Bit of a weird one for me, trying to run a github project (which had been set up with a gradle wrapper) and kept getting "classdefnotfoundexception" errors for dependencies. I checked the gradle.build file in the submodule and found dependencies were being imported using the "implementation" keyword (rather than "compile"). Once I added the "configuration.runtimeClasspath" line for the jar task issues were resolved.

Answer (score 16):

The same task can be achieved using [Gradle Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) in a similar way:

```kotlin
val jar by tasks.getting(Jar::class) {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.package.YourClass"
    }

    from(configurations
        .runtime
        // .get() // uncomment this on Gradle 6+
        // .files
        .map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) })
}
```

Answer (score 10):

previous answers are a little outdated nowadays, see here for something working with gradle-7.4:
[How to create a fat JAR with Gradle Kotlin script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794914/how-to-create-a-fat-jar-with-gradle-kotlin-script)

```
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree) // OR .map { zipTree(it) }
    from(dependencies)
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here I provide solutions for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**).
Note that the first 3 methods modify the existing `Jar` task of Gradle.

#### Method 1: Placing library files beside the result JAR

This method does not need `application` or any other plugins.

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    manifest.attributes["Class-Path"] = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .joinToString(separator = " ") { file ->
            "libs/${file.name}"
        }
}
```

Note that Java requires us to use relative URLs for the `Class-Path` attribute. So, we cannot use the absolute path of Gradle dependencies (which is also prone to being changed and not available on other systems). If you want to use absolute paths, maybe [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47961942/8583692) will work.

Create the JAR with the following command:

```bash
./gradlew jar
```

The result JAR will be created in *build/libs/* directory by default.

After creating your JAR, copy your library JARs in *libs/* sub-directory of where you put your result JAR. Make sure your library JAR files do not contain space in their file name (their file name should match the one specified by `${file.name}` variable above in the task).

#### Method 2: Embedding the libraries in the result JAR (fat or uber JAR)

This method too does not need any Gradle plugin.

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree) // OR .map { zipTree(it) }
    from(dependencies)
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Creating the JAR is exactly the same as the previous method.

#### Method 3: Using the [Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) (to create a fat or uber JAR)

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.0.0"
}
// Shadow task depends on Jar task, so these configs are reflected for Shadow as well
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "org.example.MainKt"
}
```

Create the JAR with this command:

```bash
./gradlew shadowJar
```

See [Shadow documentations](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/#configuring-the-jar-manifest) for more information about configuring the plugin.

#### Method 4: Creating a new task (instead of modifying the `Jar` task)

```kotlin
tasks.create("MyFatJar", Jar::class) {
    group = "my tasks" // OR, for example, "build"
    description = "Creates a self-contained fat JAR of the application that can be run."
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree)
    from(dependencies)
    with(tasks.jar.get())
}
```

## Running the created JAR

```bash
java -jar my-artifact.jar
```

The above solutions were tested with:

- Java 17
- Gradle 7.1 (which uses Kotlin 1.4.31 for *.kts* build scripts)

See the official [Gradle documentation for creating uber (fat) JARs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example).

For information about manifests, see [Oracle Java Documentation: Working with Manifest files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

For difference between `tasks.create()` and `tasks.register()` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53654412/8583692).

Note that your [resource files will be included in the JAR file automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24724383/8583692) (assuming they were placed in */src/main/resources/* directory or any custom directory set as resources root in the build file). To access a resource file in your application, use this code (note the `/` at the start of names):

- Kotlin

  ```kotlin
  val vegetables = MyClass::class.java.getResource("/vegetables.txt").readText()
  // Alternative ways:
  // val vegetables = object{}.javaClass.getResource("/vegetables.txt").readText()
  // val vegetables = MyClass::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt").reader().readText()
  // val vegetables = object{}.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt").reader().readText()
  ```
- Java

  ```java
  var stream = MyClass.class.getResource("/vegetables.txt").openStream();
  // OR var stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt");

  var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
  var vegetables = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
  ```

Comment: I wish I could get method 1) to work on a newer version of gradle. It is nice to retain the helper jars without flattening everything.

Answer (score 4):

`from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }`

This line is essential to me.

Comment: how to drop duplicates here?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin 1.3.72 & JVM plugin, Gradle 6.5.1

Syntax is changing quickly in all these platforms

```
tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    val main = sourceSets.main.get()
    //TODO
    register<Jar>("buildFatJar") {
        group = "app-backend"
        dependsOn(build)
        // shouldRunAfter(parent!!.tasks["prepCopyJsBundleToKtor"]) -> This is for incorporating KotlinJS gradle subproject resulting js file.
        manifest {
            attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.app.app.BackendAppKt"
        }

        from(configurations.compileClasspath.get().files.map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) })
        with(jar.get() as CopySpec)
        archiveBaseName.set("${project.name}-fat")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mainClassName = 'Main'
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java', 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}
jar{
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Main-Class": "$mainClassName",

        )

    }
    from {
configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
         }
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    dependsOn ('dependencies')
}
```

Comment: It works under jdk 1.8