# Gradle "Entry .classpath is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set"

Tags: java, gradle, build, compilation

I'm trying to build a gradle project but, when I try `$ gradle build` I get the following output:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :jar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jar'.
> Entry .classpath is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/dsl/org.gradle.api.file.CopySpec.html#org.gradle.api.file.CopySpec:duplicatesStrategy for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

After doing `Get-ChildItem -Path ./ -Filter .classpath -Recurse -Force` I concluded that
I don't even have a single file named `.classpath` in my project. What do I do?

Comment: If you're on linux or OSX, try:  `find . -name .classpath -type f` in the root folder of your project

Comment: Just checked this. I don't have any `.classpath` in my project

Comment: Also note that if the error is about an `Entry classpath.index` instead of `.classpath` (google shows this question as first answer then), it's a problem caused by intellij. see: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17236. The "entry" is actually a file which exists with the same name in different folders, this is not very clear from the error message.

Comment: @DanielAlder, thanks for your comment. It helped me a lot. I had exactly this problem.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
jar {
   duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
}
```

Comment: For people using Spring Boot plugin: replace `jar` with `bootJar`.

Comment: Similar for my case with java gradle plugin: replace `jar` with `sourcesJar`

Comment: this one is not working

Answer (score 77):

Similar to @korn answer, I solved mine using the `EXCLUDE` Strategy;

```
tasks.withType<Jar>() {

    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "MainKt"
    }

    configurations["compileClasspath"].forEach { file: File ->
        from(zipTree(file.absoluteFile))
    }
}
```

Comment: how can conflicts be `MERGED`?

Comment: Added `duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE` and it works! Magic!

Comment: this one is not working

Answer (score 25):

I was having the same issues while executing some tests in IntelliJ. What helped me was just run a simple `gradle clean`.

Comment: This one solved my case. Clean slate start sometimes did the trick.

Answer (score 13):

Please add this

`tasks.withType(Copy).all { duplicatesStrategy 'exclude' }`

In the `build.gradle` file then solved it.

Comment: Please avoid to start an answer with _I have the same problem_ because you risk to have it flagged as Not An Answer. Instead use a more affirmative text like _To solve the problem you should ....._

Comment: tasks.withType<Jar> doesn't work for me, this Copy does

Comment: This one worked for me.  It seems to depend on which task experiences a conflict.

Answer (score 7):

I faced same issue while building with kotlin and gradle 7. Resolve the issue adding the below code to your `build.gradle.kts`.

```
tasks.withType<Jar> { duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INHERIT }
```

Comment: `INHERIT` didn't work for me but `EXCLUDE` did.

Comment: `DuplicatesStrategy.INHERIT` is already the default in gradle 7 - https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:duplicatesStrategy, so setting it to the same value again might not make any difference

Comment: this one is not working

Answer (score 6):

If you use Kotlin DSL and Gradle 7.0 it may be due to that bug [KT-46165](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46165)
It should be fixed in version 1.5.0.

Answer (score 4):

Do not know about your case with `.classpath` file which you can not even find (as I know this file is usually created with Eclipse IDE which I do not use)

But I faced the same error upgrading Spring Boot app to Gradle 7.x.
My build script had additional resources processing task to support `@..@`-style placeholders (like [Spring Boot Maven build does](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.properties-and-configuration.expand-properties.maven), cause for now I support both build systems in the project and I need them to behave equal):

```
processResources {
    with copySpec {
        from 'src/main/resources'
        include 'my-app*.yml'
        include 'my-app*.yaml'
        include 'my-app*.properties'
        project.properties.findAll().each {
            prop ->
                if (prop.value != null) {
                    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [(prop.key): prop.value.toString()])
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I got the same error with Gradle 7:

> Entry my-app.properties is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy for details.

And, indeed, there is a duplicate. Gradle first copies unprocessed file to `build/resources/main` and later tries to execute my custom `processResources` and copy files again to the same place.

The solution was adding `duplicatesStrategy = 'include'` to `with copySpec {}` block. Looks like previously Gradle silently overwrote the duplicate so there was no problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there was a `com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt` exposed through dependency, while my project uses `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime`

Both resulted in jar with the same name (`jaxb-core.jar`) in classpath.

Removing `com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt` from dependency helped.
Fortunately, depencency was in my control.

Answer (score 0):

check your app level build gradle and look if you did not enter font name twice in folloing line`project.ext.vectoricons = [ iconFontNames: [  'FontAwesome.ttf','FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf','FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf','FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf',"Foundation.ttf","Ionicons.ttf","MaterialIcons.ttf","MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf","AntDesing.ttf","Entypo.ttf","EvilIcons.ttf","Feather.ttf","FontAwesome5.ttf","SimpleLineIcons.ttf","Octicons.ttf"] // Name of the font files you want to copy ]`
remove if you have any duplicate name entry worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
tasks.getByName<Jar>("jvmJar") {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same error, while building elastic search repository. Deleting the build files in build-tools-internal folder worked for me somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Go to build.gradle file and add the following

```
tasks.named("jar") {
  duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
  exclude("classpath.index")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case even after adding exclude did not work.

I havd to manually delete the `META-INF` file from src folder and to rebuild from terminal to solve the issue.