# I get this error when building my application with Gradle, task faled at ':Jar'

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Whenever I try to 'build' my program  from Gradle, I get this error. Previous to this error, I had an error that was telling me my openJDK17 did not fit with the program. I then had it run a option to fix this error, but I do not remember what option I chose.

This is on a VM that is running Ubuntu. I have Docker installed/in use as well.

```
Execution failed for task ':jar'.
> Entry Log4j-config.xsd is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy for details.
```

Comment: Have you read "https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy " ??

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68922734/8203759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @Konstantin Annikov
In the Build.Gradle of my application I added

```
 duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
```

To exclude this duplication, and it then built my program successfully.