# Unable to add duplicate strategy in gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle

Disclaimer: I am new to gradle, so it's likely I'm missing something simple.

Background: I am splitting a service into two services that will live in the same repo.  The second service (tester) uses code from the first service (engine), which I have managed to tell gradle.  But I have an issue.

Building the tester fails, giving the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':engine:processResources'.
> Entry application.properties is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set

It seems this is a common issue in gradle that someone has already posted about.  Unfortunately, pasting [each of the responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265308/gradle-entry-classpath-is-a-duplicate-but-no-duplicate-handling-strategy-has-b) in my build file has yielded nothing.

I've also tried the kotlin solutions in [this thread](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17236) with similar results: I keep getting the duplicate strategy not set error.

Surely I'm missing something but I can't for the life of me figure out what.

#### Tester build.gradle.kts Code

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.10"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.5.30"

    id("net.linguica.maven-settings") version "0.5"
}

group = "my.group"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven(url = "my/url") {
        name = "maven-snapshots"
        authentication {
            create<BasicAuthentication>("basic")
        }
    }
    maven(url = "my/other/url") {
        name = "maven-releases"
        authentication {
            create<BasicAuthentication>("basic")
        }
    }
}

//just trying all the things
rootProject.tasks.named("processResources", Copy::class.java) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
}

tasks.withType<ProcessResources>() {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
}

tasks.withType<Copy>() {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
}

tasks.withType<Jar>() {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":engine"))
}
```

Comment: The error is reporting the failing task is within the `:engine` subproject (`Execution failed for task ':engine:processResources'`). Have you tried adding the `duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.WARN` in `:engine`'s config?

Comment: Hmmm, that's gotten me a new error.   Will pursue and update with results

Comment: It seems to be causing the tester to lose reference of the engine.  Continuing to investigate