# build.gradle / JACo MP3 Player

Tags: java, gradle, mp3, minecraft-forge

I'm making Minecraft Forge MOD. It uses JACo MP3 Player, but I got runtime error when I install it to its client. It causes an error when  triggering the library event in-game:

```
[Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] An unknown error occurred while attempting to perform this command
[Client thread/INFO]: [net.minecraftforge.client.ClientCommandHandler:func_71556_a:91]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jaco/mp3/player/MP3Player
```

I don't get error when I compile or run it from Eclipse. I suspect that the library is not properly configured in the build.gradle file.

The following is `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

version = "x"
group = "x"
archivesBaseName = "x"

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs('-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8')
}

minecraft {
    version = "1.8.9-11.15.1.2318-1.8.9"
    runDir = "run"
    mappings = "stable_20"
    
    makeObfSourceJar = false
    // makeObfSourceJar = false // an Srg named sources jar is made by default. uncomment this to disable.
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/resources/libs', includes: ['*.jar'])
    
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

processResources
{
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'
        
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }
        
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

(no path issue) No information related to what I want was found anywhere.

Comment: Could you add the whole build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

You should shade it. Shading means include its dependencies into your compiled jar. Fore more information, please see [How do I create an executable fat JAR with Gradle with implementation dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278063/how-do-i-create-an-executable-fat-jar-with-gradle-with-implementation-dependenci)

Comment: what is main class?
real main class ? or used Library class?

Comment: not worked.....

Comment: @SoolSim it does not need `manifest` clause unless you want to add other properties to MANIFEST.MF because you are writing a Minecraft mod which does not have entrypoint class with the `static void main(String[] args)` method.