# Gradle Build Script Upgrade from 6.x to 7.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, webpack

I'm working on upgrading a Gradle build script from Gradle 6.9.4 to 7.x (or newer), for a SpringBoot based Java 11 web application. The original script is included below and it works correctly. The upgraded script doesn't work: the application fails to start (more details below). I could use a second pair of eyes from somebody who has more experience with Gradle and/or SpringBoot. I have very limited experience with both.

---

The "compile" and "testCompile" dependency configuration keywords have been deprecated. So in order to make the script compatible with Gradle 7.x or newer, I've had to replace both of them with alternative keywords. [According to the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/6.9.4/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management), the new-style of declaring dependencies involves replacing `compile` with `implementation` and `testCompile` with `testImplementation`.

However, simply replacing "compile" with "implementation" doesn't work. It turns out, including dependencies as "compile" results in a fat jar, but specifying them as "implementation" does not.

So I've also updated the `jar` task, based on [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278063/how-do-i-create-an-executable-fat-jar-with-gradle-with-implementation-dependenci), to make it generate a fat jar or all the dependencies. In the `jar` task, I've added the following:

```
manifest {
   attributes "Main-Class": "com.namespace.ApplicationKt"
}
from {
   configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

After making that change, running `./gradlew publish` does generate a fat jar, similar in size to the previous jar that was generated by "compile" and "testCompile".

But attempting to run it using `java -jar build/libs/output.jar` still doesn't work. It throws this exception:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:666)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:353)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1071)
    at com.amazon.duels.developer.portal.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

### Original Gradle Build Script

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.3.72'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.22.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.8.1")
        classpath("com.github.node-gradle:gradle-node-plugin:6.0.0")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'
apply plugin: 'com.github.node-gradle.node'

sourceCompatibility = 11
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
            // [.. private maven repo details here ..]
    }
}

node {    
    version = '16.20.0'
    download = true
}

task webpack(type: NodeTask) {
    inputs.file("package-lock.json")
    inputs.file("webpack.js")    
    inputs.dir("${buildDir}/resources/main")
    outputs.dir("build/resources")

    script = project.file('node_modules/.bin/webpack')
    args = ['--config', 'webpack.js']
}
webpack.dependsOn 'npmInstall'
bootRun.dependsOn webpack
build.dependsOn webpack

webpack.mustRunAfter processResources
jar.mustRunAfter webpack

bootRun {    
    apply plugin: 'application'
    mainClassName = "com.namespace.ApplicationKt"    
    args '--debug'
}

dependencies {
    //Spring
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:$springBootVersion")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")

    // Kotlin
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion")    

    // Klaxon
    compile('com.beust:klaxon:5.4')
}

// Exclude sass and js resources from the deployable jar
processResources {
    exclude '**/sass/*'
    exclude '**/js/*'
}

jar {
    exclude '**/css/*.css'
    exclude '**/js/*'
}

release {
    tagTemplate = 'v${version}'
    git.requireBranch = 'mainline'
}

publish.dependsOn build
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // [.. private maven repo details here ..]
        }
    }

    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.namespace.my-application'
            artifactId 'my-application'
            version project.version
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

/** 
 * This enables the use of ElasticBeanstalk extensions
 * .ebextension folder must be in the root of the zip/jar that is deployed to ElasticBeanstalk.
 */
bootRepackage.doLast {
    // put .ebextension and .platform in the jar for manual deployment
    exec {
        executable 'sh'
        args '-c', 'jar uf build/libs/*.jar .ebextensions .platform'
    }
}
```

---

### Updated Gradle Build Script

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.3.72'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.22.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.8.1")
        classpath("com.github.node-gradle:gradle-node-plugin:6.0.0")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'
apply plugin: 'com.github.node-gradle.node'

sourceCompatibility = 11
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
            // [.. private maven repo details here ..]
    }
}

node {    
    version = '16.20.0'
    download = true
}

task webpack(type: NodeTask) {
    inputs.file("package-lock.json")
    inputs.file("webpack.js")    
    inputs.dir("${buildDir}/resources/main")
    outputs.dir("build/resources")

    script = project.file('node_modules/.bin/webpack')
    args = ['--config', 'webpack.js']
}
webpack.dependsOn 'npmInstall'
bootRun.dependsOn webpack
build.dependsOn webpack

webpack.mustRunAfter processResources
jar.mustRunAfter webpack

bootRun {    
    apply plugin: 'application'
    mainClassName = "com.namespace.ApplicationKt"    
    args '--debug'
}

dependencies {
    //Spring
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:$springBootVersion")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:$springBootVersion")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:$springBootVersion")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")

    // Kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion")    

    // Klaxon
    implementation('com.beust:klaxon:5.4')
}

// Exclude sass and js resources from the deployable jar
processResources {
    exclude '**/sass/*'
    exclude '**/js/*'
}

jar {
    exclude '**/css/*.css'
    exclude '**/js/*'
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.namespace.ApplicationKt"
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

release {
    tagTemplate = 'v${version}'
    git.requireBranch = 'mainline'
}

publish.dependsOn build
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // [.. private maven repo details here ..]
        }
    }

    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.namespace.my-application'
            artifactId 'my-application'
            version project.version
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

/** 
 * This enables the use of ElasticBeanstalk extensions
 * .ebextension folder must be in the root of the zip/jar that is deployed to ElasticBeanstalk.
 */
bootRepackage.doLast {
    // put .ebextension and .platform in the jar for manual deployment
    exec {
        executable 'sh'
        args '-c', 'jar uf build/libs/*.jar .ebextensions .platform'
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the jar task, that destroys the spring boot jar runnability. Also remove the `$springBootVersion` from the dependencies, spring boot manages those already.

Comment: Thanks -- I've done some more reading about how spring boot implements executable Jars; I'm starting to form the opinion that the trouble is caused by an incompatibility between the spring boot gradle plugin I am using (1.5.22) and the new-style dependency declarations in Gradle 7. If this is the case then a migration to spring boot 2.x would be required before I can do anything about the Gradle script and an eventual Gradle 7 migration

Comment: I doubt it supports Gradle 7, the documentation mentions Gradle 2.9. So I would suspect an upgrade would be needed if you really wanted to do Gradle7 with Spring Boot 1.5. Which wouldn't be bad as Spring Boot 1.5 has had no support for quite a while already.